# Aumentar o tamanho de uma string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

É possível aumentar o tamanho de uma *string* no código?

```
string sIdentComanda = "";
        if (objComandaParametro.ComandaParametros[0].IsControlaNrComanda)
        {
            sIdentComanda += " Comanda: " + nrComanda;
        }
        if (objComandaParametro.ComandaParametros[0].IsUtilizaNrMesa)
        { 
            sIdentComanda += " Mesa: " + nrMesa ;
        }
```

Eu preciso aumentar o `nrMesa` para dar destaque na página. É possível.

Este é o `datalist` que é preenchido para ser apresentado na tela.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upListaVendas" runat="server" class="row">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="IdItem" DataSourceID="sdsItensPendentes"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound"
                CellPadding="0" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                GridLines="None">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-nested">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnFinalizaPreparo" runat="server" CommandName="select" CssClass="text-uppercase rounded-box">
                            <span class="clearfix">
                                <span class="pull-left text-success"><strong>Qtde.:</strong> {0}</span>
                                <span class="pull-right">{1}</span>
                                <span class="pull-right">{2}</span></br></br>
                            </span>
                            <hr />
                            <span class="clearfix text-justify">
                                <strong>Item:</strong>
                                {3} - {4} 
                            </span>
                            <hr />
                            <span class="clearfix text-justify">
                                {5}
                            </span>
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>  
                </ItemTemplate>   
            </asp:DataList>
```

E esta e a forma que o `datalist` é carregado.

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem)
    {
        LinkButton btnFinalizaPreparo = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnFinalizaPreparo");
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        string qtde = Convert.ToString(drv.Row["Qtde"]);
        string nrMesa = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(drv.Row["NrMesa"])) ? "--" : Convert.ToString(drv.Row["NrMesa"]);
        string nrComanda = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(drv.Row["NrComanda"])) ? "--" : Convert.ToString(drv.Row["NrComanda"]);
        string Apelido = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(drv.Row["Apelido"])) ? "--" : Convert.ToString(drv.Row["Apelido"]);
        string dtSolicitacao =  String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(drv.Row["dtSolicitacao"])) ? "--" : Convert.ToString(drv.Row["dtSolicitacao"]);
        string idProduto = Convert.ToString(drv.Row["IdProduto"]);
        string nomeProduto = Convert.ToString(drv.Row["NomeProduto"]);
        string complemento = Convert.ToString(drv.Row["Complemento"]);

        string sIdentComanda = "";
        if (objComandaParametro.ComandaParametros[0].IsControlaNrComanda)
        {
            sIdentComanda += " Comanda: " + nrComanda;
        }
        if (objComandaParametro.ComandaParametros[0].IsUtilizaNrMesa)
        { 
            sIdentComanda += " Mesa: " + nrMesa ;
        }
        string IdentNomeHorario = "";
        IdentNomeHorario += "Nome: " + Apelido;
        if (dtSolicitacao != "--")
            IdentNomeHorario += " " + String.Format("{0:HH:MM:ss}", DateTime.Parse(dtSolicitacao));

        btnFinalizaPreparo.Text = String.Format(btnFinalizaPreparo.Text, qtde, sIdentComanda , IdentNomeHorario, idProduto, nomeProduto, complemento);
    }

}
```

Comment: você quer aumentar o tamanho da fonte? ou vc quer concatenar uma string com outra?

Comment: Aumentar e depois concatenar.

Comment: Isto está no *controller* ou na *view*? E conforme se aumentar para você é o tamanho da fonte, sua resposta ficou ambígua.

Comment: No arquivo aspx.cs

Comment: A pergunta está pouco clara e ambígua, sem contar os erros de português.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme mostrado na resposta original, montar e exibir dados são coisas distintas, não dá para misturar. Então você precisa mudar a sua página para tratar as partes de forma separada e não pode concatenar o que é diferente.

Mudar este trecho para algo assim:

```
<span class="pull-left text-success"><strong>Qtde.:</strong> {0}</span>
<span class="pull-right">{1}</span></br></br>
<span class="pull-right"><strong>Mesa:</strong></span><span class="pull-higlight">{2}</span>
<span class="pull-right">{3}</span></br></br>
```

O `pull-higlight` foi só um exemplo, não sei como você quer destacar isto e se tem esta classe no seu CSS. Não sei se vai ser exatamente isto porque não conheço toda sua necessidade e seu código, mas é mais ou menos isso.

Também mudaria este trecho:

```
var sIdentMesa = "";
if (objComandaParametro.ComandaParametros[0].IsUtilizaNrMesa) { 
    sIdentMesa = nrMesa;
}
```

E ainda:

```
btnFinalizaPreparo.Text = String.Format(btnFinalizaPreparo.Text, qtde, sIdentComanda, sIdentMesa, IdentNomeHorario, idProduto, nomeProduto, complemento);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ChangeString.cs).

Na verdade isto está tão ruim que eu reescreveria completamente do zero e faria de forma organizada. Só porque funciona não quer dizer que está certo.

---

A pergunta mudou completamente, nem é da tecnologia apresentada inicialmente, Fica aqui a original.

Você está misturando conceitos. No seu código está manipulando dados. Em geral isto deve ser feito no *controller*, como parece que você está fazendo.

Se precisa ter determinado dado exibido de uma forma específica na página, isto deve ser feito na *view*. É feito com um HTML e provavelmente CSS.

Para facilitar o trabalho o ideal é que os dados que precisam ser exibidos de formas diferentes estejam separados. Se eles não estiverem, o código terá que separá-los antes de usar. O que dá trabalho e corre riscos, além de não ser o correto a fazer. Deve-se evitar processamento na *view*.

Até tem como colocar a forma de exibição no *controller*, mas a gambiarra é tão grande, é tão errado fazer isto que nem vou ensinar. Vai causar mais estrago que ajudar.

Então a solução é não concatenar o que você está querendo. Tem que ter o texto " Mesa: " e o número da mesa separados.

Mas pra falar a verdade, alguma coisa me diz que este texto " Mesa: " e outros textos, como o " Comanda: ", por exemplo, nem deveria estar no *controller*, isto parece ser parte da *view*.

Se tiver outros trechos relevantes do códigos, tanto no *model*, como *controller* e *view*, eu tento dar um exemplo mais completo como ficaria.

Comment: +1 pela aula e boa vontade de ajudar a pessoa não só com o problema que ele sabe que tem, mas com aqueles que ele nem percebe que tem

Comment: Bigown, obrigado pelo ajudar, vou mudar forma que esta programado e colocar os trecho do código em seu devido lugar.